# HTML inside an Email in DELPHI

Tags: html, delphi, email

Im trying to send HTML template via E-Mail directly without Copy-Paste of the Page, i mean to just put the HTML code and send it as that HTML page not Raw Text, the main reason is to send this HTML template via Delphi.

The problem is we get only the text from the HTML, i mean only this part:

```
<p>Hola chicos!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

and what i cant get it to show are these lines :

```
<table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="http://www.feelmalagahostel.com/emails/content.jpg">
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="http://www.feelmalagahostel.com/emails/header_feel_summer.jpg" style="background-position:top; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="http://www.feelmalagahostel.com/emails/footer.jpg" style="background-position:bottom; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
```

It just omits them, Shows the  tag images and not the background ones.

so thats the question how do i do it to show in an Email? and need the background images.

the HTML code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<body marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
    <table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="http://www.feelmalagahostel.com/emails/content.jpg">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="http://www.feelmalagahostel.com/emails/header_feel_summer.jpg" style="background-position:top; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!--header-->
                            <table width="730" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="230">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="100" align="right" valign="top">
                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                            <tr></tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="61" align="right">
                                        <img src="https://www.auto21.ca/userImages/images/test%20drive%20logo%20FINAL.jpg" width="347" height="61" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--end header-->
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <!--content-->
                            <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top"> <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
    <p>Hola chicos!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci </p>
    <p>velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
    </font> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--end content-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="http://www.feelmalagahostel.com/emails/footer.jpg" style="background-position:bottom; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <!--footer-->
                <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="300" valign="top"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="250">
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--end footer-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And what is the problem ? Just [`do it`](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/RLebeau/2005_08_17_A.EN.aspx) ;-)

Comment: I don't see any question here, just telling us that you want to do something.

Comment: I think that he wants to send the HTML *AS IS*, ie as text, and not as HTML. In that case, using the code provided byJachGate, you would add the strings to the email's *text* property as opposed to its HTML property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to send emails with Delphi.

My favorite is to do it via SMTP class `TIdSMTP`, part of the *INDY Project*, which is flexible and powerful.

To send a mail with HTML content use of the auxiliary class `TIdMessageBuilderHtml`, which in my opinion not only makes things easier but that leaves a much more elegant and easy to understand code.

The relevant part to send such email is:

```
var
  Builder: TIdMessageBuilderHtml;
  Msg: TIdMessage;
  SMTP: TIdSMTP;
begin
  Builder := TIdMessageBuilderHtml.Create;
  try
    Builder.Html.Add('<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>An Image for you</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>');
    Builder.Html.Add('<p><strong>An image for you</strong></p>');
    Builder.Html.Add('<div>');
    Builder.Html.Add('  <img border="0" src="cid:theimage" >');
    Builder.Html.Add('</div>');
    Builder.PlainText.Add('This mail have an image for you. '
      + 'Use a HTML viewer to see it');
    Builder.HtmlFiles.Add(ImageFileName, 'theimage');
    Msg := Builder.NewMessage();
    try
      Msg.Recipients.EMailAddresses := eRecipients.Text;
      Msg.From.Name := eFromName.Text;
      Msg.From.Address := eFromEmail.Text;
      Msg.Subject := 'A image for you';
      SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create;
      try
        SMTP.Host := eSMTPHost.Text;
        SMTP.Username := eSMTPUser.Text;
        SMTP.Password := eSMTPPass.Text;
        SMTP.Connect;
        try
          SMTP.Send(Msg);
        finally
          SMTP.Disconnect;
        end;
        SMTP.Send(Msg);
      finally
        SMTP.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Msg.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Builder.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is the first simple example about this stuff. All other examples I have tried and many troubles, this one just worked!

Comment: Sorry to ping you, I found you on the Stack Overflow in Spanish, Area 51 proposal... Could you lend a hand with this: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28330370/revisions

Comment: @apaul34208, no problem, I already re-edited the question and left a message to the OP. I hope it helps.