# Delphi - Is there any way to edit the format and layout of a SMTP email?

Tags: html, delphi, email, smtp

I'm creating a database system which sends emails out via the webmail on the hosting website 'one.com'.

With some help from this website and others, I managed to put together this email procedure. However, I do not know how to format the text within this email so that it's font, font size and color etc can be customized.

Is there a way to do this with the current code? If not, is there a way to add html edits to the email body. I've tried to add html tags to the message text, but they are not recognized as html tags. Is this due to the way the email is sent through delphi, or the way one.com works?

```
procedure SendExpiringEmail(MemName: string; ExpDate: string; MemEmail: string);
    var
      IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
      IdMessage: TIdMessage;
      IdEmailAddressItem: TIdEmailAddressItem;
      SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
      EETextFile: TextFile;
      fileline: string;    
    begin
          IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
          try
            IdSMTP.Host := 'send.one.com';
            IdSMTP.Port := 465;
            SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
            idsmtp.IOHandler :=  SSLHandler;
            IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
            IdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
            IdSMTP.Username := 'USERNAME';
            IdSMTP.Password := 'PASSWORD';
            IdSMTP.Connect;
            AssignFile(EETextFile, 'C:\MHExpEmailBody.txt');
            Reset(EETextFile);
            if IdSMTP.Authenticate then
            begin
              IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
              try
                IdMessage.From.Name := 'NAME';
                IdMessage.From.Address := 'ADDRESS';
                IdMessage.Subject := 'It looks like your membership is about to expire!';
                IdMessage.Body.Add(+MemName);
                IdMessage.Body.Add('');
                while not EOF(EETextFile) do
                  begin
                    ReadLn(EETextFile, fileline);
                    IdMessage.Body.Add(fileline)
                  end;
                IdMessage.Body.Add('');
                IdMessage.Body.Add('We look forward to seeing you. Take Care!');
                IdEmailAddressItem := IdMessage.Recipients.Add;
                IdEmailAddressItem.Address := MemEmail;
                IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);
              finally
                IdMessage.Free;
              end;
            end;
            IdSMTP.Disconnect;
            Close(EETextFile);
          finally
            IdSMTP.Free;
          end;
        end;
```

Any understanding to how things work would be greatly appreciated, as i'm still learning. Thanks.
I just need to be able to edit the format of the message and maybe add pictures if possible.

Edit: I'd just like to add that i'd prefer it if third party open source components were not offered as I find them tricky to implement.

Comment: You're using Indy. That *is* a third-party open-source component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate HTML e-mail with embedded images in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569281/generate-html-e-mail-with-embedded-images-in-delphi). See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16289577/33732

Comment: @RobKennedy cheers for that. I meant components which i have to install or other pre-built applications. apologies for the confusion. I did search for an answer, but that question never popped up. I'll have a thorough read through it. Is there any chance you could tell me how i'd go about implementing it without changing too much of my current code. Thanks

Comment: I think one of the answers I linked to demonstrates exactly what you need. I don't know how it compares to your current code, but it's *your* code, so I'll let you do the legwork.

Comment: @Babah254: All you have to do is edit your **HTML** to use whatever formatting you want, via `<font>` tags, CSS, etc. The only change you need to make to your **code** is to set the `TIdMessage.ContentType` property to `text/html` so the receiver knows the email content is using HTML. BTW, you should get rid of `AssignFile()` and `ReadLn()` (especially since you have a handle leak if an exception is raised) and just use `IdMessage.Body.LoadFromFile()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody stumbles across this, one of the links suggested before did help.
I managed to come to a conclusion after a littlw while, but i didn't have enough rep points to post an answer. Thanks for everyone's help afterwards anyway.

Add IdText to your uses clause.

Then use this code snippet:

```
with TIdText.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts, nil) do begin
  Body.Text := 'HTML goes here';
  //Or use Body.Add('HTML goes here');
  ContentType := 'text/html';
end;

IdMessage1.ContentType := 'multipart/alternative';
```

HTML tags will be recognized automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Set IdMessage.ContentType to 'text/html'. Then format your message body with HTML tags. Be sure to test your emails through a variety of email clients though. Email received as HTML have nuances in different clients. You generally rely on outdated and deprecated ways to style your email contents.

Do a web search on "creating html emails" to help you get started with how to format your HTML so that mail clients will ready it properly.

Or start here http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/creating-html-emails/